# SQL: What is the equivalent of "%" for date/time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, wildcard

The goal is to, by default, populate all the input fields of a query with a `'%'` and let the user put in real values wherever they want. However, this is causing a problem for the `DATE/TIME` field. I get the error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` How can I achieve the equivalent of `'%'` but for dates?

```
DECLARE @trans_date datetime = '%'

SELECT
   t.lp_num,
   t.trans_date
FROM ISW_LPTrans AS t
WHERE t.trans_date = @trans_date
```

**Edit:** - Removed the `LIKE` and replaced with `=` because people kept focusing too much on that and it's **not** the focus of this question.

Comment: If itrans_date is a datetime and should be treated as such, search for date *ranges* using BETWEEN / DATEDIFF / DATEPART etc else you would need to cast the column to a character type which is inefficient and not overly useful for most search scenarios.

Comment: How is the user inputting data? Is it from an external source or directly inside of the DBMS?  I am not 100% sure about 2008 but I use 2014 and you can use LIKE '%' directly with the Date.  The issue is that you are trying to save the string '%' as a date time.  When you use LIKE it treats it different (compared to using an = sign).

Comment: @Cody360c it will be through Report Builder 3.0's interface. So through a report.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Do you absolutely need the DECLARE?

Comment: @Cody360c No, it's just that LinqPad forces me to use that. In Report Builder 3.0, you don't need it.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat If you don't need it then could you do what Rahul Tripathi said?  If it does not work in the DECLARE but it does work in the SELECT then just try and skip the DECLARE if possible.

Comment: I think there was an another answer here before, but someone erased it. That answer worked, but I didn't accept it because I wanted to test it a few times. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  Your query doesn't make sense.  `LIKE` is for *strings* and dates are not strings.

If you like, you can convert the date to a canonical string format and then use that.

However, date pickers are the more typical solution for choosing dates, and the resulting code does not use `LIKE`.

Comment: The overarching goal is to allow users in Report Builder 3.0 to either leave the default `%` value in the input field or put in their own date. That is, by default the query should return all dates and then narrow it down by a specific date only when the user provides a real date. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat . . . Normally, the application would choose either a single date or range of dates and pass that as parameters into the query.  When the parameters are `NULL`, then all dates would be chosen.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was trying to accomplish - trying to replicate the effect of choosing all dates, but from the query side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use LIKE keywords directly on dates. LIKE is mostly used for string values.

However you can use the [CONVERT functio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx)n to cast your date as varchar and then apply the LIKE keyword. For example:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), trans_date, 126) LIKE '2016-10-01%'
```

> The goal is to, by default, populate all the input fields of a query
>   with a '%' and let the user put in real values wherever they want.

If you want that user should be allowed to enter a date then you can simply provide **NULL** value to your date column instead of populating it with a % value(*which is absolutely vague for a date column*)

Comment: Is that something only in early versions of SQL-Server? I am using 2014 and I can use LIKE directly with Date

Comment: @Cody360c - It implicitly casts it to `varchar` still and specifying a format at least gives you a clue as to the correct format to use if you do want an exact match.

Comment: @MartinSmith So basically just some healthy programming practices.  Not necessarily needed but could become very useful.  Better to do it yourself then hope it gets done correctly for you.

Comment: @Cody360c To be clear I do *not* think casting a datetime column to string in order to do wildcard searches in any way represents "healthy programming practices". It completely removes any possibility of index use for one.

Comment: @MartinSmith No.  I mean doing the cast yourself rather than having the DBMS do it for you.  It is kind of like if you were to do C# or something along the lines of that and rather than let the program decide for you if something is public/private you should just do it yourself.  Basically I mean do something yourself to guarantee it does what you want rather than hope it does what you want.

Comment: @Cody360c - Yes, the implicit cast seems to be `CONVERT(varchar(40),getdate(),0)` which is `Jul 21 2016  2:04PM` for me - but for someone with different language settings the string from the default casting behaviour will be different.